# How to protect std::queue from growing too much

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I'm writing a program on a MIPS that runs embedded Linux (openWRT).

The program opens a TCP connection to a server and bridges it with a serial port. The data exchange is two-way.

```
Serial Port <--> TCP Socket
```

I have two `std::thread`. One for reading data from the serial port and one for reading data from the TCP socket.
To keep things simple I wrap data into a class that contains a vector.
The read function returns an object `Packet` that contains the vector with the data.
The `Packet` object is pushed into a `std::queue` that the other thread reads. I use two queues, one for reading data and one for writing.

My concern is when the TCP socket is not available for instance, ethernet cable unplugged, or for whatever other reason that the device cannot connect. The `std::queue` will grow because the other end, in this case the serial port thread will add data into it.

Is there any way to avoid that?

One solution I can think of is to add messages mechanism between threads and implement simple message handlers like `onConnect`, `onDisconnect` etc that will simply synchronize the threads and avoid bottleneck.

What else can I do?

Comment: "_that will simply synchronize the threads and avoid bottleneck._": How does that work? What do you do with the serial data that can't be transmitted? If you just want to drop packets, simply checking the size of the queue for a maximum before inserting would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is simply have the thread appending to the queue stop reading from its socket/port handle until the queue gets to a reasonably sized state.  You can easily do this with condition variables and a reasonable timeout

Your data structure for the queue. I'm guessing you already have something that pairs a mutex with a queue.  We just add on the cv.

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mut;
std::queue q;
```

Then to write to the queue:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    while (q.size() >= TOO_BIG)
    {
        cv.wait(); // also wait_for if you need a reasonable timeout
    }
    q.push(packet);
}
```

And your thread that reads from the queue:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mut);
    if (q.size() > 0)
    {
       packet = q.front();
       q.pop();
       cv.notify_all(); // wake up the thread blocked on wait()
    }
}
```

You can also extend the above technique to have your thread wait for an item to get enqueued instead of polling it.

One thing that can happen is that if the TCP socket gets too backed up for writing, then you'll effectively not be reading anything from the serial port for some time. This could lead to data loss if the upstream source generating serial data can't push its data through.

Alternatively, you could simply empty the queue once it gets excessively large.

Either way, there's no free lunch when the upstream pipe stalls and a flood of data comes in from the other source.